# Custom log file name in mule using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, mule, log4j2

I'm trying to change the log file name generated by mule by modifying the `log4j.xml` to have the appropriate appender.

Here 's a snippet from the `log4j.xml`

```
 <RollingFile name="Rolling-Async-Perf" fileName="/usr/local/mule/logs/${app_name}.log"
            filePattern="./logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/perf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz"  immediateFlush="false">
```

Here's how I set the value of `application_name` in the class that loads the properties related for `log4j.xml`

```
System.setProperty("app_name", "AppName");
```

However, the file generated has the name `${app_name}.log` rather than `AppName.log`.

Any thoughts on how  I could get mule to pick up the name of the file based on the custom property in mule?

Answer (score 0):

Two options are:

1) add a property in the MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf file for example:

```
wrapper.java.additional.15=-Dapp_name=AppName
```

or 2) inside the Configuration element of your log4j2.xml file [example here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html):

```
<Properties>
  <Property name="app_name">AppName</Property>
</Properties>
```

Comment: I'm currently doing this and its not working for me.  I have  multiple apps on the same mule container with a single `wrapper.conf` and a single `log4j.xml` file . I want to inject the `app-name` dynamically for this reason.

Comment: what is not working? can't you add a variable for each application each time you deploy?

Comment: All the services would be deployed together at the same time. In terms of an example. Consider there are 3 apps with names `appA`,`appB`,`appC`. And I wanted to have logs from `appA` to go to `appA.log` , `appB`->`appB.log`etc. What value would I have to provide in `wrapper.conf` or in the `log4j2.xml` in place of `AppName` ? Since there is only ONE of those on the container.